# Freeing edges in a linkedList

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, valgrind, free

I implemented a simple version of make called mymake, basically it creates a linked list putting file names in NODES and using EDGES to link them. I'm having trouble freeing edges inside a linkedList, following is valgrind report(*** indicates personal info) and please ignore output because it's irrelevant:

```
***@***:~/***/***/mymake$ valgrind -q --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes mymake makefile3 1
5
6
7
2
9
10
4
8
3
1
==1285== 192 bytes in 8 blocks are indirectly lost in loss record 1 of 2
==1285==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1285==    by 0x40108C: linkList (in /***/***/***/***/***/mymake/mymake)
==1285==    by 0x400AEF: main (in /***/***/***/***/***/mymake/mymake)
==1285== 
==1285== 288 (96 direct, 192 indirect) bytes in 4 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
==1285==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1285==    by 0x40102C: linkList (in /***/***/***/***/***/mymake/mymake)
==1285==    by 0x400AEF: main (in /***/***/***/***/***/mymake/mymake)
==1285==
```

I'm pretty sure that the linked list is freed because there is no leak in function buildList(which use NODE to build the linked list), but in function linkList(uses EDGE to link some nodes), there are still leaks.
Here is my freeing function:

```
void freeList(){
    node *node0, *node1;

    node0 = root;
    while (node0 != NULL){
        edge *edge0, *edge1;

        node1 = node0->next;
        edge0 = node0->depends;
        while (edge0 != NULL){
            edge1 = edge0->next;
            free(edge0->from);
            free(edge0->to);
            free(edge0);
            edge0 = edge1;
        }
        free(node0->target);
        free(node0);
        node0 = node1;
    }
}
```

and here is linkList() function:

```
void linkList(FILE *fp){
    char word[64+1] = "";
    bool isTarget = true;
    node *mainTar = NULL;
    edge *currE = NULL, *nextE = NULL;
    int i = -1;
    while (fscanf(fp, "%s", word) != EOF){
        i++;

        if (isTarget == true){
            if (i == 0)
                continue;
            if (i == 2)
                continue;
            if (strcmp(word, "@cmd") == 0){
                isTarget = false;
                i = 0;
                continue;
            }
            if (i == 1){
                mainTar = findNode(word);
                if (mainTar->isTarget == true)
                    printError("Duplicated target:", word);

                mainTar->isTarget = true;
            }
            else{
                if (mainTar->depends == NULL){
                    currE = malloc(sizeof(edge));
                    if (currE == NULL)
                        printError("Error: out of memory!", "(edge)");

                    currE->from = mainTar;
                    currE->to = findNode(word);
                    currE->next = NULL;
                    mainTar->depends = currE;
                }
                else{// mainTar->depends != NULL
                    nextE = malloc(sizeof(edge));
                    if (nextE == NULL)
                        printError("Error: out of memory!", "(edge)");

                    nextE->from = mainTar;
                    nextE->to = findNode(word);
                    nextE->next = NULL;
                    currE->next = nextE;
                    currE = nextE;
                }
                //printf("%s\n", currE->to->target);
            }

        }

        // isTarget == false
        else{
            if (strcmp(word, "@target") == 0){
                isTarget = true;
                i = 0;
                continue;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I'm so desperate because I've spent more than an hour working on it and made no progress, but I know I'm almost there, could you help me please? Much appreciation in advance :)

Edit: following are declarations:

```
struct n;

typedef struct e{
    struct n *from;
    struct n *to;
    struct e *next;
} edge;

typedef struct n{
    char *target;
    char *cmd;
    bool isTarget;
    bool visited;
    struct e *depends;
    struct n *next;
} node;
```

can't free memories allocated for EDGE.

Comment: Please show how `node` and `edge` are declared.

Comment: Can there be multiple references to a node or edge? Is the dependency graph acyclic?

Comment: Declarations added. @MichaelWalz

Comment: Circular Dependency is NOT allowed in this one. @joop

Comment: (I wouldn't bet on that, given the node->edge and edge->node pointers) But multiple references *are* allowed? --> add reference counts.

Comment: What do u mean by multiple references? @joop As far as I can tell, all memory regarding nodes are freed, only those regarding edges aren't freed.

Comment: Multiple references: two edges pointing to the same node. Or: two nodes pointing to the same edge.. Or: two {node or edge}s pointing to the same {node or edge}

Comment: Oh ok, so multiple references do exist, but that's not the issue here, right?

Comment: I found out that edge0 itself is null when first assigning node0->depends to it, that means node0->depends is null, right? Do you know what happened?

Comment: It's really hard to tell because there are to many unknowns in your question. How does `linkList` influence the global namespace? What is `root` pointing to? How is `findNode` implemented? ...

Comment: @Crysishy Do you set `node0->depends` to `NULL` somewhere else? Make sure that you reach `currE = malloc(sizeof(edge));`. Further, `free(edge0->from);` and `free(edge0->to);` seems to be wrong and should lead to double frees.

Comment: You also don't release `*cmd` in case you allocate it somewhere else. As said already: hard to tell without complete code!